# Can I search for co-op games in Steam?

Tags: steam

I saw the options to search by publisher or genre. Is there a way to specify that I want to search for games with co-operative multiplayer support?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, using the advanced search options in the Steam store, one can see all games with co-op support.

Here is the list: http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=9

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to search for coop games *that I own*